# App Engine, pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed"

Tags: python, mongodb, google-app-engine, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I'm using Python 3.7 and Flask 1.0.2

> **I plugged my app to mongoDB Atlas, and all works fine in local**
>
> client = pymongo.MongoClient(connector)

connector is my standard connection string given by Atlas

```
connector = "mongodb://xxx:<PASSWORD>@xxcluster-shard-00-00-y0phk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,xxcluster-shard-00-01-y0phk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,xxxcluster-shard-00-02-y0phk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=xxxCluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"
```

When I deploy my app to Google App Engine standard Python3 runtime environment, it does not works. Would anyone have an idea of the problem?

**Code:**
[image]
**Log of Appengine:**
[image]

**Local log(works fine in local):**
[image]

**Appengine error:**

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection
>   closed,connection closed,connection closed"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The problem was the Ip Whitelist, thus I have add via the vpc peering
>   connection with gcp.
>
> To do simple, we can add 0.0.0.0/0 to allow access from anywhere(but,
>   be careful)

.

Comment: 0.0.0.0/0 definitely works. Is there any better (secured) way to handle this apart from VPC peering?

Comment: if your applications are in AWS, you can also setup a private endpoint: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-private-endpoint/

Comment: I believe that this answer does not put caveats about security. Basically this solution it's open the database to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had `ssl=False`. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is the Network Access configuration in your MongoDB whitelist.
After adding your IP the problem should be solved.
Keep in mind that the IP address must be IPv4.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to setup a peering connection between your network and the mongodb cluster's network with the [VPC Peering feature of Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering). Way more secure ;)

Make sure to follow the instruction for a [Private only connection](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/faq/connection-changes/#connstring-private). to do so, you need to adjust the URI by adding -pri.

Example:

```
old_con = "mongodb://xxx:<PASSWORD>@xxcluster-shard-00-00-y0phk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,xxcluster-shard-00-01-y0phk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,xxxcluster-shard-00-02-y0phk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=xxxCluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"
new_con = "mongodb://xxx:<PASSWORD>@xxcluster-shard-00-00-y0phk-pri.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,xxcluster-shard-00-01-y0phk-pri.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,xxxcluster-shard-00-02-y0phk-pri.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=xxxCluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"
```

Comment: this should be the way, but I had to temporarily allow access from anywhere 0.0.0.0/0 coz peering option is restricted (FEATURE UNAVAILABLE IN FREE AND SHARED-TIER CLUSTERS) as per the [doc](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/)

Comment: gotcha! I also faced that issue recently. Hours of pain. In that case, unless you deploy your application in VMs you control instead of App Engine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb#private-ip), you won't be able to set an External IP and whitelist it in Atlas. Personally, if the application is connecting to a DB, I wouldn't expose it to the net with App Engine, unless it's for a quick PoC/test.